# How can I programmatically change the border of a rectangle in WPF (storyboard animation)?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

In order to change a color of a rectangle in code behind I can use:

```
        InitializeComponent();

        StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        myStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(20);

        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.Name = "MyRectangle";

        // Create a name scope for the page.
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

        this.RegisterName(myRectangle.Name, myRectangle);
        myRectangle.Width = 100;
        myRectangle.Height = 100;
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        this.RegisterName("MySolidColorBrush", mySolidColorBrush);
        myRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
        SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        myRectangle.StrokeThickness = 4;
        myRectangle.Stroke = blackBrush;

        ColorAnimation myColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
        myColorAnimation.From = Colors.Blue;
        myColorAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
        myColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myColorAnimation, "MySolidColorBrush");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myColorAnimation,
            new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
       Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation);


        myRectangle.MouseEnter += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            myStoryboard.Begin(this);
        };

        myStackPanel.Children.Add(myRectangle);
        this.Content = myStackPanel;
```

How can I do the same for the border of the rectangle (actually I'm looking more for a blinking-border effect than the fading one, maybe by changing Stroke property)?

Comment: As you wrote, `Stroke` property is ok for you. Plese insert your `Rectangle` and `MySolidColorBrush` definition. Because the way to modify `Stroke` property is similar to modify  `Fill` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `Stroke`:

```
    SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    this.RegisterName("MySolidColorBrush", mySolidColorBrush);
    myRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

    SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    this.RegisterName("MySolidColorBorderBrush", blackBrush);
    myRectangle.StrokeThickness = 4;
    myRectangle.Stroke = blackBrush;
```

And storyboard setup

```
ColorAnimation myColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
myColorAnimation.From = Colors.Black;
myColorAnimation.To = Colors.Blue;
myColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myColorAnimation, "MySolidColorBorderBrush");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myColorAnimation,
        new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

myStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation);
```

---

Just for the archive (xaml)

```
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="4">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.Stroke>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBorderBrush" Color="Black" />
        </Rectangle.Stroke>
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Blue" To="Red" />
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Black" To="Blue" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid writing code in xaml (in order to control better the behaviour of the rectangle from the code behind, i.e. in c#).

Comment: if you don't want to write code in xaml, U have to leave WPF as soon as possible. Your code will be huge... anyway edit... please insert your code, where you create your `Rectangle` and define your `Brush` and I insert my into this..

Comment: I don't mind writing XAML code, the thing is that the rectangle border will have to change according to many different rules that will be defined in code behind.
Maybe I expressed myself poorly but I was expecting an answer that modifies Stroke property (for me Stroke == Border, am I wrong?).

Comment: Yeah but in this case I didn't have a choice :). Thank you for your help!